# What is APP partition in Ubuntu during system configuration?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, nvidia, system-installation

I am setting up Ubuntu 18.04 on an Xavier NX (using the NVIDIA sdkmanager to flash the device), which is a single board computer with an ARM processor. I am at the system configuration on first boot where I enter username, password, language, etc... Now, I am at this window that says "Please enter desired size of APP partition in Megabytes (MB)."

The current size is ~14000 MB, and the maximum size I can input is ~1TB, which is the size of the hard drive. What is the APP partition? I've never heard of this, and I don't know what I should enter.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the screen and add it to your question?

Comment: Oh, I should have done this. I just picked the max size and proceeded, and I’ll try to look at the partitions once the install is complete. Im thinking this is specific to the Jetson images from nvidia.